# Reduce space between title and plot

Tags: r, radar-chart

How to make radarchart print titles closer to the actual graph? Notice the space btw title and graph below:
[image]

MWE:

```
radar_data <- data.frame(
# Add max and min automatically
  RMSEA = c(0.00974, 1.000, 0.998),
  CFI =   c(0.17202, 0.773, 0.659),
  TLI =   c(0.03231, 0.996, 0.988)
)

rownames(radar_data) <- c("iv_ri_clpm", "heise", "starts")
radar_data <- rbind(rep(1,3) , rep(0,3) , radar_data)

# png(filename = "radar_chart.png")
# Reduce plot margin using par(
opar <- par(mar = c(4, 4.1, 4.1, 2.1))
# Define settings for plotting in a 3x4 grid, with appropriate margins:
# par(mar = rep(0.3,4))
par(mfrow = c(1,3))
# Produce a radar-chart for each student
for (i in 3:nrow(radar_data)) {
  radarchart(
    radar_data[c(1:3, i), ],
    pfcol = c("#99999980",NA), axistype = 1, 
    # Customize the grid
    cglcol = "grey", cglty = 1, cglwd = 0.8,
    # Customize the axis
    axislabcol = "black", 
    pcol= c(NA,2), plty = 1, plwd = 2, 
    caxislabels = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1),
    title = row.names(radar_data)[i]
  )
}
# Restore the standard par() settings
par <- par(opar) 
# dev.off()
```

- How to remove the space above and below the graph?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the line that the title is on:

```
for (i in 3:nrow(radar_data)) {
  radarchart(
    radar_data[c(1:3, i), ],
    pfcol = c("#99999980",NA), axistype = 1, 
    # Customize the grid
    cglcol = "grey", cglty = 1, cglwd = 0.8,
    # Customize the axis
    axislabcol = "black", 
    pcol= c(NA,2), plty = 1, plwd = 2, 
    caxislabels = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1),
  )

#change title line (may need to experiment with #)
  title(paste(row.names(radar_data)[i]), adj = 0.5, line = -22)
}
```